# Adding a property inside an object that has been filtered from an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have this array of objects ("clients") which I compare with another array called "contracts" that have some IDs that appear in "clients".

I have already filtered "clients" and I'm able to find which objects have the same id. However, I can't add a new property inside that object!

Here are examples of both arrays

CLIENTS:

```
const clients = [{"id":"a0ece5db-cd14-4f21-812f-966633e7be86","name":"Anna","email":"annap@quotet.com","role":"user"},
{"id":"e8fd159b-57c4-4d36-9bd7-a59ca13057bb","name":"Jack","email":"jackp@quotet.com","role":"admin"},
{"id":"a3b8d425-2b60-4ad7-becc-bedf2ef860bd","name":"Barnett","email":"barnettp@quotet.com","role":"user"},
{"id":"44e44268-dce8-4902-b662-1b34d2c10b8e","name":"Merrill","email":"merrillp@quotet.com","role":"user"},
{"id":"0178914c-548b-4a4c-b918-47d6a391530c","name":"Whitley","email":"whitleyp@quotet.com","role":"admin"},
{"id":"a74c83c5-e271-4ecf-a429-d47af952cfd4","name":"Lamb","email":"lambbp@quotet.com","role":"user"},
{"id":"55601290-8619-4f54-b831-9c6c26c52b44","name":"Ophelia","email":"opheliap@quotet.com","role":"user"},
{"id":"1470c601-6833-48a4-85b4-ddab9c045916","name":"Jerry","email":"jerryp@quotet.com","role":"user"}];
```

CONTRACTS:

```
const contracts = [{"id":"64cceef9-3a01-49ae-a23b-3761b604800b","amountInsured":"1825.89","inceptionDate":"2016-06-01T03:33:32Z","installmentPayment":true,"clientId":"e8fd159b-57c4-4d36-9bd7-a59ca13057bb"},
{"id":"7b624ed3-00d5-4c1b-9ab8-c265067ef58b","amountInsured":"399.89","inceptionDate":"2015-07-06T06:55:49Z","installmentPayment":true,"clientId":"a0ece5db-cd14-4f21-812f-966633e7be86"},
{"id":"56b415d6-53ee-4481-994f-4bffa47b5239","amountInsured":"2301.98", "inceptionDate":"2014-12-01T05:53:13Z","installmentPayment":false,"clientId":"e8fd159b-57c4-4d36-9bd7-a59ca13057bb"},
{"id":"6f514ec4-1726-4628-974d-20afe4da130c","amountInsured":"697.04", "inceptionDate":"2014-09-12T12:10:23Z","installmentPayment":false,"clientId":"a0ece5db-cd14-4f21-812f-966633e7be86"},
{"id":"25202f31-fff0-481c-acfd-1f3ff2a9bcbe","amountInsured":"2579.16", "inceptionDate":"2016-05-03T04:58:48Z","installmentPayment":false,"clientId":"a0ece5db-cd14-4f21-812f-966633e7be86"},
{"id":"15b4430d-96f8-468e-98c0-3caaf8b0b3b6","amountInsured":"645.65", "inceptionDate":"2016-01-15T02:56:48Z","installmentPayment":true,"clientId":"a0ece5db-cd14-4f21-812f-966633e7be86"},
{"id":"5a72ae47-d077-4f74-9166-56a6577e31b9","amountInsured":"751.67", "inceptionDate":"2015-08-05T04:05:01Z","installmentPayment":true,"clientId":"e8fd159b-57c4-4d36-9bd7-a59ca13057bb"},
{"id":"4a582500-fab6-4efe-ae89-0c9ed750d0c7","amountInsured":"3074.24", "inceptionDate":"2014-06-24T09:21:06Z","installmentPayment":false,"clientId":"a0ece5db-cd14-4f21-812f-966633e7be86"}]
```

The following code compares the id from the array "clients" with the "contracts" one.

FILTERING CODE:

```
clients.filter((e) => {
    return contracts.some((j) => {
      return e.id === j.clientId
    })
})
```

It works, it ends showing that two clients are the ones that have the contracts. I thought that changing the previous code to the next one would add as many porperties as contracts tha same client has:

```
clients.filter((e) => {
        return contracts.some((j) => {
            if (e.id === j.clientId) {
                clients.push(e[j.id] = {
                    "amountInsured": j.amountInsured,
                    "inceptionDate": j.inceptionDate,
                    "installmentPayment": j.installmentPayment
                })
            }
        })
})
```

But it doesn't work...
As you can see, my idea is **to add properties from objects from the array "contracts" that have the same id than "clients" so I can have the array "clients" updated with these properties**. Because there can be many contracts with the same id (clientId), I need to add the property name ina dynamically way (I0ve chosen to use the id of the contract).

I would really appreciate any help,
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Filter returns a new array so when you're appending values to the clients they are being assigned to the unfiltered array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is really inefficient if you have contracts and clients of large size.  For small arrays it will perform fine, and may be slightly faster, because it avoids some object initialization and iterating over an integer indexed homogeneous array is fast.
But the code is very short and concise.
You can use an object map if the size of the arrays can be very large (so clientId lookups can be O(1)).

(Put all contracts under one object)

```js
for (const client of clients) {
  const mycontracts = contracts.filter(c=>c.clientId===client.id)
  if(mycontracts.length)
    client.contracts = Object.fromEntries(
      mycontracts.map(({id, clientId, ...data}) => [id, data]))
}
console.log(
  clients
)
```

```html
<script>
const clients = [{"id":"a0ece5db-cd14-4f21-812f-966633e7be86","name":"Anna","email":"annap@quotet.com","role":"user"},
{"id":"e8fd159b-57c4-4d36-9bd7-a59ca13057bb","name":"Jack","email":"jackp@quotet.com","role":"admin"},
{"id":"a3b8d425-2b60-4ad7-becc-bedf2ef860bd","name":"Barnett","email":"barnettp@quotet.com","role":"user"},
{"id":"44e44268-dce8-4902-b662-1b34d2c10b8e","name":"Merrill","email":"merrillp@quotet.com","role":"user"},
{"id":"0178914c-548b-4a4c-b918-47d6a391530c","name":"Whitley","email":"whitleyp@quotet.com","role":"admin"},
{"id":"a74c83c5-e271-4ecf-a429-d47af952cfd4","name":"Lamb","email":"lambbp@quotet.com","role":"user"},
{"id":"55601290-8619-4f54-b831-9c6c26c52b44","name":"Ophelia","email":"opheliap@quotet.com","role":"user"},
{"id":"1470c601-6833-48a4-85b4-ddab9c045916","name":"Jerry","email":"jerryp@quotet.com","role":"user"}];
const contracts = [{"id":"64cceef9-3a01-49ae-a23b-3761b604800b","amountInsured":"1825.89","inceptionDate":"2016-06-01T03:33:32Z","installmentPayment":true,"clientId":"e8fd159b-57c4-4d36-9bd7-a59ca13057bb"},
{"id":"7b624ed3-00d5-4c1b-9ab8-c265067ef58b","amountInsured":"399.89","inceptionDate":"2015-07-06T06:55:49Z","installmentPayment":true,"clientId":"a0ece5db-cd14-4f21-812f-966633e7be86"},
{"id":"56b415d6-53ee-4481-994f-4bffa47b5239","amountInsured":"2301.98", "inceptionDate":"2014-12-01T05:53:13Z","installmentPayment":false,"clientId":"e8fd159b-57c4-4d36-9bd7-a59ca13057bb"},
{"id":"6f514ec4-1726-4628-974d-20afe4da130c","amountInsured":"697.04", "inceptionDate":"2014-09-12T12:10:23Z","installmentPayment":false,"clientId":"a0ece5db-cd14-4f21-812f-966633e7be86"},
{"id":"25202f31-fff0-481c-acfd-1f3ff2a9bcbe","amountInsured":"2579.16", "inceptionDate":"2016-05-03T04:58:48Z","installmentPayment":false,"clientId":"a0ece5db-cd14-4f21-812f-966633e7be86"},
{"id":"15b4430d-96f8-468e-98c0-3caaf8b0b3b6","amountInsured":"645.65", "inceptionDate":"2016-01-15T02:56:48Z","installmentPayment":true,"clientId":"a0ece5db-cd14-4f21-812f-966633e7be86"},
{"id":"5a72ae47-d077-4f74-9166-56a6577e31b9","amountInsured":"751.67", "inceptionDate":"2015-08-05T04:05:01Z","installmentPayment":true,"clientId":"e8fd159b-57c4-4d36-9bd7-a59ca13057bb"},
{"id":"4a582500-fab6-4efe-ae89-0c9ed750d0c7","amountInsured":"3074.24", "inceptionDate":"2014-06-24T09:21:06Z","installmentPayment":false,"clientId":"a0ece5db-cd14-4f21-812f-966633e7be86"}]
</script>
```

Comment: I see, you are right with both things. I didn't realize that it could be inefficient. It's true that it would be better to add "contracts" as a property. I didn0t know about flatMap so it is good to hear about it! 
However, I need these two clients to be in the "client" array, just with the property added. 
Do you think is it possible to do so with the previous code or I should do it in another way? Taking into account what you said I'll think about the map object. Thanks!

Comment: Using `some` will not work because it stops at the first true match.  If you are doing it for optmization purposes, it would only be optimized because it doesn't take all contracts into account, which is not what you want.  You want all matching contracts to be added.  What you are asking for is actually easier.  It can be a clean two line for-of loop.  I've added in an if statement so it doesn't add contracts if there aren't any.

Answer (score 0):

Some should return boolean and because filter returns a new array, something like this would work:

```
let filteredClients = [];
filteredClients = clients.filter((e) => {
        return contracts.some((j) => {
            if (e.id === j.clientId) {
                e[j.id] = {
                    "amountInsured": j.amountInsured,
                    "inceptionDate": j.inceptionDate,
                    "installmentPayment": j.installmentPayment
                }
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        })
});

console.log(filteredClients);
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the work:

```
for (let j in clients) {
    for (let i in contracts) {
        if(contracts[i].id==clients[j].id){
            clients[j].amountInsured = contracts[i].amountInsured;
            clients[j].inceptionDate = contracts[i].inceptionDate;        
            clients[j].installmentPayment = contracts[i].installmentPayment;
        }
    }
}
```